# Apache Cordova 5 vs. prior version 4

Tags: apache, cordova, intel-xdk

**TL;DR** Should I update my app from Cordova 4 to Cordova 5? Any advantages? What are the key differences?

Apache Cordova 5 has been released a few months ago. So I'm looking for some good reasons that encourage me to update my app to the newer version. The informations on the blog https://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/04/21/tools-release.html don't give me good reasons why I should do so as they don't say anything about performance improvements or other things that would improve my almost finished app. Does anybody have a better insight?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would say if it ain't broke, don't fix it.  From what I can tell, Cordova 5 requires some careful updates in your code and settings, some of which are described here:

http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/05/25/important-information-about-cordova-5

If you're really "almost done" I would stick to Cordova 4, but of course in time Cordova 5 will become the norm, and I expect Cordova 4 will eventually fade away.